# Wordpress shows wrong time on same configuration

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, timezone

I have identical configuration on both dev and prod servers. But in production wordpress shows me wrong utc time. It can't be plugin because it's a fresh installation of wordpress. I even tried to use production database and rsynced all files from production to development to keep everything identical, but still same problem.

You can see my configuration in screenshots below:

Dev:
[image: Development server]

Prod:[image]

phpinfo()

dev: 
[image]

prod:
[image]

date('Y-m-d H:i:s') function:

dev:
[image]

prod:
[image]

And now wordpress settings:
dev:
[image]
prod:
[image]

Comment: what's the time difference?

Comment: In the last screenshot you can see, that wordpress somehow use localtime as utc time.

Comment: no, there is always a 2 hours difference - and I don't know when you have taken these screenshots - so I don't know what the actual time was back then.

Comment: I made those screenshot at same tame. There can be few seconds or minutes difference. That's obvious :) Correct UTC time was about 13:50 local - 15:50. In production wordpress settings, it shows UTC time 15:50 - that's wrong. But everywhere else (server console, phpinfo, time()) - it's correct.

Comment: Where are both servers located?

Comment: Both are Located in Lithuania. What's the difference? As you can see, both servers have same tz configuration, also, both of them shows correct time in console. And both of them shows same time from php date('Y-m-d H:i:s') function. Only wordpress shows wrong datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found the answer [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/utc-time-wrong/page/2/) .

> It appears that there was an issue with the time zone database initially provisioned to your server in which the UTC time zone was improperly set to EDT. We were able to resolve this issue by re-installing the tzdata package.

After installing tzdata package everything works properly.